# Two Types of Routes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, routes

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/something', (_) => false);

Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/something', (route) => false);
```

Hi what is the difference of this two? What's happening with routes and with underscore (_)???

Comment: It has nothing to do with the routes, "_" indicates you don't need that parameter, and you will not be using it

Comment: So what happens when using routes?

Answer (score 1):

The _ operator is using when we are not accessing the object.

route is of type `Route<dynamic>` you can access the properties of `Route` class.

Comment: So what happens when using routes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference whatsoever when it comes to routing.

The only thing the underscore (`_`) indicates is that you, as a programmer, is not interested in using the builder argument (`route`) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the parameter however you like. All these are the same:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/something', (route) => false);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/something', (foo) => false);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/something', (bar) => false);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/something', (test) => false);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/something', (whatever) => false);
```

`_` is used when you are not interested in the parameter. That you as developer won't be doing anything with the parameter.